# QListWidget rows overlaping each other

Tags: c++, qt

First of all I am apologizing for my English in advance. I am trying to display a custom widget in a QListWidget, but when more than one row is added, they are displayed on the same spot.

[image: My application desing]
<sub>(source: [minespeed200.de](https://minespeed200.de/stackoverflow/images/projectDesing.png))</sub>

Settings of the QListWidget

```
    alternateingRowColors:true
    movement:Static
    isWrapping:false
    resizeMode:adjust
    layoutMode:singePass
    spacing:1
    viewMode:listMode
```

i've already tried all of the possible settings for this values. if there is another importent one i've missed (i am fairly new to Qt) please tell me. Also the row colors seem to overlap too (the picture of my application below has 2 rows added), what tells me, that not only the widget's but the row's are overlapping each other entirely.

[image: My custom widget desing]
<sub>(source: [minespeed200.de](https://minespeed200.de/stackoverflow/images/coustomWidget.png))</sub>

[image: The resulting overlap of rows]
<sub>(source: [minespeed200.de](https://minespeed200.de/stackoverflow/images/application.png))</sub>

I am adding the rows with this code:

```
item=new QListWidgetItem();
QSize size(this->width(),this->height());
item->setSizeHint(size);
list->addItem(item);
list->setItemWidget(item,this);
```

Inside of the constructor of my custom widget class.

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but calling width() and height() inside the constructor of a widget may return wrong values because the widget size is fully initialized only after it is first shown on screen. You can try to use item->setSizeHint(this->sizeHint()) instead.

Comment: This is good to know, but when i try it i get the same resutlt.

Comment: @Gabriella Giordano This is a very interesting idea. But I think that here the matter is in the list itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that i left the gridSize of my QListWidget at it's default value and the y component had to be set to the height of my widget i was displaying.
Adding:

```
    list->setGridSize(QSize(0,this->sizeHint().height()));
```

fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this method.

```
   list->QListWidget::setFlow(QListWidget::LeftToRight)
```

check here: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#flow-prop

Comment: If i change the flow direction to LeftToRight, everything gets pushed together even more and i actually want the rows to flow from top to bottom (the lable's and button's are in their own widget).

Comment: Ok i actually found my mistake. I had left the grid size on it's default value (0,0) and after i set it to the heigth of my widget the rows got layed out properly.

Comment: @MemoryFragmentation So hard and so fun my friend. Next time, please drop your full code.